# Setting up color for the link of active page in navbar, python flask

Tags: python, html, css, flask, jinja2

i want to have the current page (on which the user is currently on) link to have a different color than the other page links, so user knows which page they are on. using this on python flask.

this is part of my layout.html

```
<ul class="nav">
     <li {% if request.path == '/' %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ url_for('index') }}">Home</a></li>
     <li {% if request.path == url_for('browse') %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ url_for('browse') }}">Browse</a></li>
     <li {% if request.path == url_for('details') %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ url_for('details') }}">Details</a></li>
     <li {% if request.path == url_for('profile') %} class="active"{% endif %}><a href="{{ url_for('profile') }}">Profile <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='assets/images/profile-header.jpg') }}" alt=""></a></li>
     <!-- Add more items as required -->
</ul>
```

This is my app.py

```
from flask import Flask, render_template, request

app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route('/')
def index():
    return render_template('index.html', request=request)

@app.route('/browse')
def browse():
    return render_template('browse.html', request=request)

@app.route('/details')
def details():
    return render_template('details.html', request=request)

@app.route('/profile')
def profile():
    return render_template('profile.html', request=request)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run()
```

i have used {% if request.path == url_for('browse') %} class="active"{% endif %}>%} but failed

Answer (score 0):

it seems like all of your class names are the same "active", so i dont see how can you change your css if you dont change your class names. All if statements refers to same class, so you can create different classes in your css file and refer them in your if statements.

Answer (score 0):

NVM I figured it out, used javaScript and fixed it, here's the solution

```
<script>
// Get the current page URL path
 var currentPath = window.location.pathname;
                
// Get the menu item with a matching URL and add the "active" class
 if (currentPath === "{{ url_for('index') }}") {
  document.getElementById("home").classList.add("active");
  } else if (currentPath === "{{ url_for('browse') }}") {
  document.getElementById("browse").classList.add("active");
  } else if (currentPath === "{{ url_for('details') }}") {
   document.getElementById("details").classList.add("active");
  } else if (currentPath === "{{ url_for('profile') }}") {
           document.getElementById("profile").classList.add("active");
  }
</script>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).